# How to instantly update an item within a list of data with firebase and angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the following code that produces a list of items from firebase, where I can update each item by clicking a button. But I'd like to update a specific item within the list instantly using $bind instead of having to click submit everytime.

I'm currently updating the list with the below script (jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/ryuvg6bz/) which requires the user to press submit, but I'd like it to be instant for item within the list

HTML

```
<section ng-app ="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-repeat= "(id,item) in data">
        <input ng-model="item.comment"></input>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="AddComment(id)">Comment</button>
</div>

</section>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"])
    .controller('MyController',function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com");

    $scope.data = $firebase(ref);


    $scope.AddComment = function (id) {
        $scope.data.$save(id)}


});
```

My attempt is the following

```
<section ng-app ="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-repeat= "(id,item) in data">
        <input ng-model="item.comment"></input>
</div>

</section>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"])
    .controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com");

    $scope.data = $firebase(ref);

    function (id) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com/" + id + "/comment");
        $firebase(ref).$bind($scope, "comment");

    }


});
```

Comment: This code uses an older version of AngularFire and is not applicable to >= 0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-change` to save the data immediately like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id,item) in data">
    <input ng-model="item.comment" ng-change="AddComment(id)"></input>
</div>
```

**Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/snk9Ld23/1/